# PHP: Not going to the next page

Tags: php, button

I have a little problem with my code and I don't know what is wrong in my code... So I have a two form where the first load is the "view.php" then the second is "checkbox_building.php".. My problem is when I removed the button of delete in "view.php" the dropdown list can proceed to "checkbox_building.php". but when I placed it back, its not working (its not proceeding to "checkbox_building.php") I'm kinda confuse about this.

Here's my code for "view.php"

```
<fieldset  width= "200px">  
    <form name='form' method='post' action=''>
    Select Network: <select name="netName" onChange="this.form.action='checkbox_building.php'; this.form.submit()">
    <option value="" >- Select -</option>   
    <?php

    include 'connect.php';
    $q = mysql_query("select fldNetname from tblnetwork");

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
    echo "<option value='".$row1[fldNetname]."'>".$row1[fldNetname]."</option>";
    $net = $row1[fldNetname];

    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete Building/s' onClick="this.form.action='delete_building.php'; this.form.submit()">
</form>
    </fieldset>
```

thanks.!

Comment: change the <input type="submit" to <button type="button"

Comment: @DevZer0..still the same :(

Comment: Do you get any errors on your browsers developer console/Firebug etc ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem...no error...

Comment: you have `</fieldset>` but no matching `<fieldset>`

Comment: @yitwail...sorry... for my incomplete code... I have <fieldset> i forgot to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just as a guess, just from your code:

correct the  flaw, then
change

```
<input type='submit' name='submit'
```

to

```
<input type='button' name='dosubmit'
```

and

```
<form name='form' method='post' action=''>
```

to

```
<form name='<someUsefullName>' method='post' action=''>
```

and all references to this as well, since "form" is a reserved word in IE and `this.form.action` may lead to errors there.

Comment: The submit button submits the form, regardless what's in the onClick handler. Taking just a plain `button` prevents that - you may leave it with `submit` and instead have a `return false;` in your `onClick`, same effect. And naming an element the same as its tag type (like `<form name="form"...`is in general an error source.

Comment: @AxelAmthor..thanks for the explanation...I'll keep in mind what you said :)

Answer (score 1):

just remove `name='submit'` and try

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete Building/s' onClick="this.form.action='delete_building.php'; this.form.submit()">
```

so it will be

```
<input type='submit' value='Delete Building/s' onClick="this.form.action='delete_building.php'; this.form.submit()">
```

its because `this.form.submit` is default submit function, but in your code its an `input` element :)

Comment: same with the name here: after `<input type='submit' name='submit'` this.form.submit refers to the button and renders an `... is not a function...` error.

Comment: yeah, instead of removing you can also replace the name with some other name, like `submit1`, `dosubmit`, `submit_btn`, etc.. but not `submit` :)